# unexpected token: IGNORE required: INTO in HSQLDB

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hsqldb, ibatis

It is said that HSQLDB supports MYSQL `insert ignore` syntax [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/changelist_2_0.txt).
But I still have an exception when using it. Is there a way to fix it? Or it is not actually supported?(my HSQLDB version is 2.4.0)

Here's exception:

```
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: IGNORE required: INTO in statement [INSERT IGNORE INTO Error    (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4) VALUES       
       ( ?, ?, ?, ?)]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.instantiateStatement(PreparedStatementHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.prepare(BaseStatementHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.prepare(RoutingStatementHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doUpdate(BatchExecutor.java:70)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    ... 39 more`
```

Comment: OK, so I've figured out solution for this exact case. you just need to add `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE;`  to accept IGNORE token. But there's still problem inserting record with non-existing foreign key which MySQL handles without problems.

But in HSQLDB I still have exception:

`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: com.wellcentive.dhub.resultprocessor.mapper.node.BatchErrorMapper.insertErrors (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FKERRORDATAPOINT table: ERROR`

Comment: Do you mean such inserts are ignored by MySQL?

Comment: @fredt yes. but are not ignored by HSQLDB